# Remove concat and IIF function for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How to convert my SQL Server 2012 statement so it's compatible with SQL Server 2008?

I know that SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported by Microsoft but one of our clients is still using it.

This is my SQL Server 2012 query:

```
IIF(@Filter = '', 1, 0) + CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', Group_ID, ','), CONCAT(',', @Filter + ',')) > 0
```

One of our client is on SQL Server 2008 and `IIF` and `CONCAT` are not supported, so I want to change the above query:

What I tried is :

```
Where @Filter = case when @Filter= '' then 1 + CharIndex(',' + convert(varchar(100),Group_ID) +',',',' + @Filter+',') 

                                            when @Filter <> '' then 0 + CharIndex(',' + convert(varchar(100),Group_ID) +',',',' + @Filter+',')
                         END
```

It doesn't produce any error but my output is blank.

Can someone please suggest what needs to be done please

Comment: SQL Server 2012 isn't supported either. Even 2014 is out of mainstream support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing condition succeeds if `@Filter` is not the empty string or if `group_id` belongs to a CSV list that is stored in `@Filter`.

I would express this with `OR` and `LIKE`; I find that it is easier to understand the intent this way without using `charindex()` (but that's also a matter of taste):

```
WHERE
    @Filter = ''
    OR ',' + @Filter + ',' LIKE '%,' + convert(varchar(100),Group_ID) +',%',
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the same:
2008

```
case when case when @Filter= '' then 1 else 0 end +
    CharIndex(','+Group_ID+',',','+@Filter+',') > 0
```

if equivalent to your
2012

```
IIF(@Filter = '', 1, 0) + 
CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', Group_ID, ','), CONCAT(',', @Filter + ',')) > 0
```

Comment: How to add charindex > 0 logic here

Comment: Adjusted my answer Red

Answer (score 0):

You should user WHEN CASE syntax instead IIF and "+" aggregate instead CONCAT